# Is wheel performance unbeatable?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Is it possible to tell or prove if common inflatable wheel is the best possible concept?

May something like say Pedrail wheel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedrail_wheel or some kind of rubber coated chain belts, human like mechanical legs, etc. have better rolling resistance or overall power transfer efficency?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a design question, it is more of an engineering one. From a physical perspective, losses at the wheel / surface interface (not the bearing it is rotating in which is another source) arise mostly from slip between the wheel and surface and offset between the resultant vertical and the axis of rotation. To minimize the second, you want an infinitely stiff wheel that contacts the ground at a point (in three dimensions, the contact is a line parallel to the axis of rotation). This is why we pressurize tires and why low pressure leads to decreased mileage. However, to not slip, you need some deformability and stickiness. This is what "slicks" are for on drag race cars. There are all sorts of other issues. Practical tires have tread for water to evacuate, slicks do not (hence the name), which is why you can watch videos of all the race cars sliding out of control because a little rain started.

I am not sure if a theoretical "proof" could be developed of the best design, because the best design is an infinitely stiff thin circular hockey puck with basically infinite friction coefficient.